# Expo push notification icon & title

Tags: react-native, push-notification, icons, expo

I didn't find the way to set up  icon and name on notification push. I have updated app.json and run expo publish but notification display always Expo icon and title. Here my app.json, did i miss something ?
Thanks

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "app",
    "slug": "app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "privacy": "public",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/notification.png",
      "iosDisplayInForeground": true
    },
    "android": {
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true
    },

    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#23317B"
    },

    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this config.

```
"notification": {
  "icon": "./images/Logo.png",
  "color": "#311b92",
  "androidMode": "default",
  "androidCollapsedTitle": "Updates from Colab.notes",
  "iosDisplayInForeground": true
}
```

Make sure you have the correct icon and icon path.

The expo icon and title are displayed if you are running the app on Expo mode.
To resolve that you need make the app build and run the apk.

Comment: This only works for Android, do you know how to get the app icon as the push notification icon for iOS?